# Odds of 2 people sharing the same exact ticket set of a size up to 38

Tags: probability, distributions, dataset

- Say user 1 entered the raffle 18 times (18 tickets) and he had ticket ids **[0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 14, 16, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33]** (so they acquired the first ticket, missed the second (2nd hour ticket) then acquired the 3rd 4th missed ticket 5 through 7...and so on)
- Now say user 2 had the exact ticket set as user1, they acquired the same tickets as user, and missed the same ones as user1, thats 100% match

> Heres a set i got with a 100% match users `'--lzyyy', '--yBunny', '--atB', '--ranhamoose25', '--bysmc', '--atree12', '--n_Halen', '--kemoo', '--aayBa'` all had the same exact ticket set of size 20
> `[7,8,9,15, 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37]`
>
> this just seems so astronomically improbably

So here's my question, having `750` total users. What are the odds that with a `total acquirable tickets of 38` that 2 users share the same exact ticket sets, and what are the odds that an x amount of users having this exact ticket set [1,3,4,7,9,19,20,21,22,23,24,29,30,31,32,33,35,36]

i did some calculations to find out the odds of someone having a specific amount of tickets, and the odds of a user acquiring a specific ticket and the results are as below:

**ODDS OF A USER ACQUIRING A SPECIFIC TICKET**

> - Odds of a user acquiring the 1st ticket of the
>   month is **38.49%**

```json
{
  '0': 0.38491048593350385,
  '1': 0.46930946291560105,
  '2': 0.47570332480818417,
  '3': 0.3989769820971867, 
  '4': 0.5971867007672634, 
  '5': 0.5754475703324808, 
  '6': 0.618925831202046,  
  '7': 0.5,
  '8': 0.5434782608695652,
  '9': 0.5971867007672634,
  '10': 0.5997442455242967,
  '11': 0.6355498721227621,
  '12': 0.5281329923273658,
  '13': 0.6649616368286445,
  '14': 0.49744245524296676,
  '15': 0.5396419437340153,
  '16': 0.5792838874680307,
  '17': 0.592071611253197,
  '18': 0.69693094629156,
  '19': 0.6751918158567775,
  '20': 0.6253196930946292,
  '21': 0.6406649616368286,
  '22': 0.6560102301790282,
  '23': 0.3312020460358056,
  '24': 0.6841432225063938,
  '25': 0.7480818414322251,
  '26': 0.7506393861892583,
  '27': 0.717391304347826,
  '28': 0.7237851662404092,
  '29': 0.6010230179028133,
  '30': 0.5959079283887468,
  '31': 0.7161125319693095,
  '32': 0.6521739130434783,
  '33': 0.7531969309462916,
  '34': 0.7097186700767263,
  '35': 0.6764705882352942,
  '36': 0.4961636828644501,
  '37': 0.6023017902813299
}
```

**ODDS OF A USER HAVING A SPECIFIC AMOUNT OF TICKETS**

> - Odds of a user of the 750 users to have at least 32 total tickets is **12.02%**

```json
{
  '0': 0,
  '1': 1,
  '2': 1,
  '3': 1,
  '4': 1,
  '5': 1,
  '6': 1,
  '7': 1,
  '8': 1,
  '9': 1,
  '10': 1,
  '11': 1,
  '12': 1,
  '13': 1,
  '14': 1,
  '15': 1,
  '16': 0.9258312020460358,
  '17': 0.850383631713555,
  '18': 0.7749360613810742,
  '19': 0.7225063938618926,
  '20': 0.6381074168797954,
  '21': 0.5549872122762148,
  '22': 0.4859335038363171,
  '23': 0.44501278772378516,
  '24': 0.3938618925831202,
  '25': 0.34271099744245526,
  '26': 0.2966751918158568,
  '27': 0.26342710997442453,
  '28': 0.2340153452685422,
  '29': 0.20332480818414322,
  '30': 0.17135549872122763,
  '31': 0.14194373401534527,
  '32': 0.12020460358056266,
  '33': 0.09207161125319693,
  '34': 0.06905370843989769,
  '35': 0.052429667519181586,
  '36': 0.03964194373401535,
  '37': 0.023017902813299233,
  '38': 0.008951406649616368
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, Rafat. There are two issues here.  The purely combinatorial one is an instance of the [birthday paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=birthday+paradox), which you can find solved here on CV by following the link.  The statistical one concerns your implicit assumption that all tickets have the same chances of being acquired and their acquisitions are independent. In the circumstances you describe that's highly unlikely. For instance, the ticket associated with an unpopular hour won't be acquired by many viewers. Thus, the combinatorial result probably is unrealistic.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment whuber, i just edited my question to include the probability of a user acquiring a specific raffle ticket. I will look into birthday paradox, this is all new to me and is starting to interest me a lot. thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $N$ users and $T$ tickets. Each user has $B$ tickets. What is the probability that at least two users have identical ticket sets?

Let $X = (x_1, \ldots, x_T)$ be a vector of $0,1$ variables with probabilities $p_0, \ldots p_T$ and let $X_j$ be the configuration of player $j$

There are ${T}\choose{B}$ possible configurations so, by the pigeon hole principle, the probability of a collision is 1 for $N > {{T}\choose{B}} = M$.

The probability of selecting a specific configuration is
$$
a(x) = \prod_{j=1}^T p_jx_j + (1 - p_j) (1-x_j)
$$

Enumerating all possible configurations allows us to say that $X_j$ takes an integer value in the range $0, M$. Let $a(m)$ denote $a(x)$ for the $x$ corresponding to $m$<sub>(This is just done to simplify notation)</sub>. Now assume $N < M$. For $N = 2$ you get
$$
P(X_1 = X_2) = \sum_{m=1}^{M} P(X_2 = m \mid X_1 = m)P(X_1 = m)
= \sum_{m=1}^{M} a(m)^2
$$
Let $A_{jk} = X_j\cap X_k = \varnothing\forall j,k$. Then
$$
P(\texttt{No collission}) = P(X_k\cap X_j = \varnothing\forall j,k) = P(A_{jk}) = P(A_{1k} \mid A_{j>1,k>1})P(A_{j>1,k>1})=\cdots\\
= \prod_{\ell = 1}^N P(A_{j=\ell,k>\ell} \mid A_{j>\ell,k>\ell})
$$
And
$$
P(A_{j=\ell, k>\ell} \mid A_{j>\ell,k>\ell}) = 1 - P(X_\ell \in \cup_{k=\ell+1}^N X_k \mid \texttt{unique}).
$$
$$
P(X_\ell \in \cup_{k=\ell+1}^N X_k \mid \texttt{unique})
 = \sum_{j=1}^{M} a(m)P(m\in \texttt{unique} \cup_{k=\ell+1}^N X_k)
$$

Remaining work:

1. Calculate $P(m\in \texttt{unique} X_{(\ell+1):N})$, the probability that configuration $m$ is in the mutually exclusive draws.

Comment: Hey hunaphu, thank you for the detailed answer and for taking the time. This right here is a defining moment in my life, and it has become vividly clear to me that i urgently need to reevaluate my life decisions, what is life after all...? and hereby i give you my upvote and will accept this answer, it is the lease i could do.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) with an additional problem to compute the number of days in a year (the number of ways to have 15 or more tickets).

In R, I compute these number of birthdays using the function to compute the binomial distribution, which adds up all possible ways to get a certain number of zero's and ones `(1-pbinom(15,38,0.5))*2^38` and this gives 255181990352 possibilities.

Then using this with the approximate formula for at least a collision in the birthday problem gives

$$p(n,d) \approx 1 - \left( \frac{d-1}{d} \right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$ and $$p(750,255181990352) \approx 1.100679 \cdot 10^{-6}$$

However, the probability will be higher when you consider that certain combinations are more likely (e.g. some hours of broadcasting might be more likely, and also some total number of hours might be more likely). When we consider 750 viewers with exactly 15 tickets then you get `dbinom(15,38,0.5)*2^38` possibilities and a twenty times higher probability.